# Помогите составить запрос для elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

В mysql это выглядело бы так

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE 
(`birthday`='2000-05-01' AND `country_id`=3546 AND `city_id`=1276 AND `name` LIKE '%Марина%') OR 
(`birthday`='1983-05-23' AND `country_id`=3456 AND `city_id`=1235 AND `name` LIKE '%Саша%') OR

..................................................................................................

(`birthday`='1983-04-12' AND `country_id`=3456 AND `city_id`=1235 AND `name` LIKE '%Глаша%')
```

Какой запрос будет для elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы работаете с `elasticsearch` советую установить [плагин Head](http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/) с помощью которого вы легко бы построили данный запрос, что касается поиска, так почитайте документацию (к примеру [search api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html)) где `should` это массив логических ИЛИ, а `must` это массив логических И. Попробуйте использовать запрос такого вида:

```js
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "birthday": "2000-05-01",
                  "country_id": "3546"
                },
                "term": {
                  "name": "Марина"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "birthday": "1983-05-23",
                  "country_id": "3456"
                },
                "term": {
                  "name": "Саша"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```